# API 3 Link to video not showing

Tags: php, api, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm trying to use the Vimeo API to pull a list of all the videos for a user who's videos are public, but the information in the JSON that's being returned doesn't include the element "files" under each entry and which should contain the link to the videos in various formats. What's going on here?

As a side question, I just posted a question yesterday with the exact same question above regarding the API and a Vimeo staff member just informed me that "Vimeo" doesn't support the "Vimeo API". So disregarding the obvious irony there, who is it that creates and supports the Vimeo API? A third party that has been contracted/outsourced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "files" field only shows up on videos for PRO members who request their own videos. You must be authenticated as the owner of the video. If your goal is to play these videos, you should use [OEmbed](http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed) to request our embed iframe.

As for support, I am the Senior API Developer at Vimeo and personally handle the majority of API support cases. Can you please let me know where you previously posted your question? If it was in the forums, those are left over from a previous time and are not supported. We will soon move everyone to our Google Group.

All API support has moved to [Email](https://vimeo.com/help/contact) for private conversations, [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vimeo-api) for public conversations, and here on Stack Overflow for programming help.

Comment: Thank you for that response. It was very helpful. The link for when I posted the question is here https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:116737 . So, yes, it was in the forums, but thank you for clarifying about the move to Google Groups. Do you have the link to that by the way? Also, the member I'm trying to pull videos from is "testeverything". They're a pro member who make all their videos public and downloadable, so I was just assuming that I could get the video link through the API. I am developing a private Roku channel of these videos and have already contacted the member about such.

Comment: Our google group is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vimeo-api.

For your testeverything user, if they have authenticated to your app you should be able to see their source files. We don't expose download links via the API for various security concerns.