# Play vimeo video in VIMVideoPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, vimeo-api, video-player, vimeo-player

I need to develop an app which will play vimeo videos. Now, Vimeo officially provide a class named VIMVideoPlayer to play videos. (https://github.com/vimeo/VIMVideoPlayer)

I also wondering if there is any other way to get success but videos with vimeo url like 'https://vimeo.com/136061500' not working with it. I need to achieve this. Please provide your help to get over on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VIMVideoPlayer only works with direct links to video files. If you are a Vimeo PRO user, and own the video, you can get direct link access, but those links are not accessible to other users videos.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, i'm  vimeo PRO user. How i get access to direct link access. If you little light up this, it will be surely useful.

I also read your answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470786/youtube-vimeo-api-mp4-files#22483199

Comment: Use the VIMNetworking library to make API requests. From there, you will see your files in any request that returns your videos, such as https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos